# Ubuntu Mate - Enable Compose key (and disable compose key behavior by default)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-mate, 20.04

I have upgrade to ubuntu mate 20.04 yesterday and now my typing acts as though I have the compose key permanently pressed. If I want to type, say a back quote (`) or this acute (^) I must press the key twice, which is quite annoying.
I don't need those characters to type stuff like é, but rather scripts, regex, markdown or vim and the like use them. So I often need to type those characters but really rarely do I need to type accented letters.

Before I was able to just press the key and it would pop up straight away. How do I get that functionality back?

I have tried enabling the compose key (in the hopes that it will disable that annoying system), but it didn't help. I have also tried to switch from `105 key generic (intl.)` to `104 key generic` (not international), but that didn't help either.
I really don't even know how to word this for searching.

My keyboard layout is set to "german", I set my compose key to capslock and it does seem to do stuff. Like compose + c + c = č
But what I want doesn't work with or without the compose key set. Also what is that "3rd Level" stuff?

[image: Keyboard Layout Setting]
[image: Compose Key Setting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the *German (dead acute)* keyboard layout, which may fit your needs. It's described like this:

> modify the basic German layout to have only acute as dead keys (ASCII
>   grave, tilde and circumflex are needed as spacing characters in many
>   programming languages and text formatters)

(quoted from `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/de`)

Comment: I selected german (no dead keys) because dead acute still had some two key combinations with backquotes. but thank you.